# Haskell IO: Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io

```
playerInstruction :: [String] -> Int -> [String]
playerInstruction mapList count = do
    if count == 0
        then printf "First direction : "
        else printf "Next direction : "
    inp <- getLine
    case inp of
        "Up" -> instructionProc mapList Up
        "Down" -> instructionProc mapList Down
        "Left" -> instructionProc mapList Leftx
        "Right" -> instructionProc mapList Rightx
        otherwise -> playerInstruction mapList count
```

This is a part of the code of a project I am working on. This is a function to take in the player's instruction and redirect the player to another function. **mapList** is a list of String which supposed to contain the changes of the map step by step. **count** is the variable to count the number of instructions the player has input. The problem I am encountering is that the compiler is saying the line

```
inp <- getLine
```

having an error. With a message as stated in the topic. I am not sure how to fix this problem. Please feel free to see this link: [Haskell IO: Reading the whole text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65272777/haskell-io-reading-the-whole-text-file) if you want to know more about this project. Thank you.

Comment: You've declared `playerInstruction` as a pure function, but `getLine` is impure; the types don't line up. Have you tried to remove the type declaration to see what happens?

Comment: What type of `instructionProc` is? In any case, `playerInstruction` should return `IO [String]` as @MarkSeemann says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the function as `IO` in the signature:

`playerInstruction :: [String] -> Int -> IO [String]`